# Using LINQ's Except<> method with an object from an external API

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List<> of HTMLAnchor objects (HTMLAnchor is an object from an external API). I want to exclude clicking on some of the links as they are for logging out, etc.

Using LINQ, I can use the Except operator. However, on here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336761.aspx#except1), the example using the custom type (Product if I remember correctly) does not use the overloaded version of Except.

Furthermore, if I am using a type not defined by me, do the rules change? And should the class I write to implement IEquality have the same name I am trying to exclude in my generic collection (HtmlAnchor)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compare anchors using the default Equals method, which in this case will probably give you reference equality, you don't need to do anything: just pass the set of anchors to exclude:

```
anchors.Except(anchorsToExclude);
```

If the members of the sequence to exclude will not be reference-equal (or whatever HtmlAnchor.Equals deems equal), the interface you want to implement is `IEqualityComparer<T>`.  This exists precisely to allow you to provide a custom equality comparison for a type that you don't define, so the rules don't change -- you just have to use the appropriate overload of Except.

So you would create a class called e.g. HtmlAnchorEqualityComparer which implements `IEqualityComparer<HtmlAnchor>`, and pass an instance of that to Except:

```
anchors.Except(anchorsToExclude, new HtmlAnchorEqualityComparer())
```

Answer (score 1):

When you don't have control over the type, and the default equality operations do not suffice (ie. Equals is not properly implemented), you should use [the overload which takes an IEqualityComparer<T> parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390.aspx). This is a class that you can implement yourself to provide the definition of equality, that you need.